# Is starmap faster than a nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools

Here is a code solving the task from [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximizing-xor/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=24-hour-campaign):

```
def maximizingXor(l, r):
    return max([i^j for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)])
```

And here is my ugly solution:

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap
from operator import xor

# Complete the maximizingXor function below.
def maximizingXor(l, r):
    return max(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2)))
```

its not so beauty like that one, but really faster on l=10, r=15:
%timeit shows 3.81 µs ± 156 ns for my solution and 8.67 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop for solution without functions calling.
So here is the question - why faster?
And more generally:
In what cases function calling like itertools is faster then direct cycling?
Thanks.

Comment: The list comprehension has to allocate memory for O((r-l)**2)) values, and *then* it can iterate though them all and  pick the largest. Yours only needs constant memory, keeping or discarding each value as it is generated.

Comment: There is no need to use a list comprehension in the initial code. Is a generator expression faster? Note that for some expressions, helpers such as ``map`` can indeed be faster than comprehensions.

Comment: aside from the creation of the list, `itertools` constructs can be quite fast compared to hand-written python versions. They are implemented in C.

Comment: @chepner, ah - really - no optimization. May be propose it to developers?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets that will not change. If you write a list-comprehension, Python should create a list. You cannot optimize this in principle, because nothing stops you from doing `max = some_other_function` You *can* use a generator expression, but that may not be *faster* unless the list gets quite large, since generators are slow, and Python is really good at creating lists of things.

Comment: The comprehension variant creates, uses and destroys about ``r-l`` additional ``range`` objects and their iterators. The itertools variant can directly compute all pairs from one ``range`` object. Just creating a list of 5 ``range`` objects requires about 90% of the difference in the initial timings on my machine.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is answer i think. thx )

Comment: @VasylKolomiets It has the same *effect*; it's implemented entirely in C and can do something much more efficient, because you have requested a particular *result*, rather than giving instructions on how to produce that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note `max` works with any iterable. This could be a list *or* a generator. Which is more efficient depends on the size of your inputs and your hardware constraints. Lists are memory hungry, but generator expressions have larger overheads from `next` calls.

The timings below are for 2 different runs on 4 variations of the same logic. As you can see, for very large `l, r` the generator expression is more efficient than the list comprehension, and vice versa for smaller `l, r`.

`starmap`, also lazy but avoiding the generator expression, is more efficient than both. In layman's terms, `starmap` has the best of both worlds by being lazy *and* using optimized C code for iteration.

```
# run 1 inputs
l, r = 10000, 15000

# run 2 inputs
l, r = 1000, 1500

%timeit maximizingXor_lc(l, r)   # 2.83 s per loop, 18.2 ms per loop
%timeit maximizingXor_ge(l, r)   # 2.48 s per loop, 21.5 ms per loop
%timeit maximizingXor(l, r)      # 1.53 s per loop, 15.2 ms per loop
%timeit maximizingXor_zip(l, r)  # 6.52 s per loop, 51.7 ms per loop
```

#### Benchmarking code

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap
from operator import xor

def maximizingXor_lc(l, r):
    return max([i^j for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)])

def maximizingXor_ge(l, r):
    return max(i^j for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1))

def maximizingXor(l, r):
    return max(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1), 2)))

def maximizingXor_zip(l, r):
    return max(map(xor, *zip(*combinations(range(l,r+1), 2))))

assert maximizingXor_lc(l, r) == maximizingXor(l, r)
assert maximizingXor_lc(l, r) == maximizingXor_ge(l, r)
assert maximizingXor_lc(l, r) == maximizingXor_zip(l, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I posted this with the incorrect code. It is faster to find the maximum of a list than the maximum of a generator. If the range is small enough to fit in memory, you will have faster results creating a list and finding the maximum than not.

```
def maximizingXor_lst(l, r):
    return max(list(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l, r+1), 2))))
```